# How to add a '?' in HTTP request in POSTMAN

Tags: postman

My POST request header is similiar to this http://192.168.202.42/abc/def.cgi?
But when i send this request above with POSTMAN, i always see only 
http://192.168.202.42/abc/def.cgi getting sent i.e., without the '?'.
This seems to be troubling the server. How to send the '?' using POSTMAN ?

Comment: add a query param `http://192.168.202.42/abc/def.cgi?test`

Comment: That worked !!! Thanks Andrew !